# Unable to push docker images into my docker hub account

Tags: image, docker

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Docker version - 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

I want to push docker images to my docker hub account.

I used below command to login to my docker hub account.

> docker login

And for pushing the docker image, this is the command I entered:-

> docker image push hub/image

where hub/image is the name of the docker image.

I'm getting an error, which states :-

"The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/nginx]
m8915cb5x5: Preparing 
ybbf139faa: Preparing 
lb1560xa9e: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

I also checked my docker hub auths via:-

> cat .docker/config.json

It seems to be fine.

Please help me figuring out the issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is the image in your namespace? I.e. is the image-name `<your username on docker-hub>/image`?

Comment: Nope, i added a tag to an existing image.  so it shows hub/image as the image name

Comment: It needs to have your name before the slash though.

Comment: This is the output I get if I use my username before the image name: 
root@ip-172-32-43-2:~# docker image push louddoc/hub/image
The push refers to repository [docker.io/louddoc/hub/image]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: louddoc/hub/image

Comment: try to tag your image on louddoc/image and push

Comment: It worked!! Thanks @lvthillo

Comment: Thanks to you too @tkausl